# How do we change the value of the variable while in Callback in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, callback, null

I'm trying to make a messaging app and I ran into a problem. My problem is, I use SearchView in the application, allowing users to search each other by typing usernames. The appearance of the data after searching varies depending on whether they are friends and whether they have sent a friend request. To do this, I assign the value from my callback function to the value I created and then return this value in getItemViewType. When I use println to check the incoming value, I see that the value is updated while in the callback, and the value is in its old state outside the callback, what do you think could be the reason? Thank you from now.

**getItemViewType**

```
 override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val user = userList[position]
    var rowViewType = 0

    rowManager.changeViewType(user,object : RowListener{
        override fun rowViewType(viewTypeNumber: Int) {
            rowViewType = viewTypeNumber
            when(rowViewType){
                0->{println(user.username+" ile arkadaş değilsiniz")}
                1->{println(user.username+" ile arkadaşsınız")}
                2->{println(user.username+"'a istek gönderdin")}
                else->{println("FAIL")}
            }
        }
    })

    when(rowViewType){
        0->{println("Return "+user.username+" ile arkadaş değilsiniz")}
        1->{println("Return "+user.username+" ile arkadaşsınız")}
        2->{println("Return "+user.username+"'a istek gönderdin")}
        else->{println("Return "+"FAIL")}
    }

    return rowViewType
}
```

**changeViewType method of RowManager**

```
fun changeViewType(user: UserModel,rowListener: RowListener){
    var myViewType:Int = 0
    userManager.isFriend(user.id!!,object : UserListener{
        override fun onUserSuccess() {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
        override fun onUserDataSuccess(user: UserModel?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
        override fun onUserListSuccess(userList: ArrayList<UserModel>?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
        override fun onIsFriend(status: Boolean?) {
            if(status!=null){
                if(status==true){
                    myViewType = 1
                    rowListener.rowViewType(1)
                }
                else{
                    requestManager.isSendRequest(userManager.getCurrentUserId(),user.id!!,object : RequestListener{
                        override fun onRequestSuccess() {
                            TODO("Not yet implemented")
                        }

                        override fun onRequestFail(error: String) {
                            TODO("Not yet implemented")
                        }

                        override fun onRequestListSuccess(requestList: ArrayList<UserModel>) {
                            TODO("Not yet implemented")
                        }

                        override fun onIsRequestSend(status: Boolean) {
                            if(status==true){
                                rowListener.rowViewType(2)
                            }
                            else{
                                rowListener.rowViewType(0)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        override fun onUserFail(error: String) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
}
```

**isFriend method of UserManager**

```
 fun isFriend(id:String,userListener:UserListener){

    db.collection("Users").document(auth.currentUser!!.uid).collection("Friends").document(id).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->

        val result = task.result
        result?.let {
            if(it.exists()){
                userListener.onIsFriend(true)
            }
            else{
                userListener.onIsFriend(false)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**isSendRequest method of RequestManager**

```
    fun isSendRequest(senderId:String,receiverId:String,requestListener: RequestListener){

    db.collection("Users").document(receiverId).collection("Requests").document(senderId).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        val result = task.result

        result?.let {
            if(it.exists()){
                requestListener.onIsRequestSend(true)
            }
            else{
                requestListener.onIsRequestSend(false)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

When I started out using android I was facing the same issue.

The problem basically is here

```
 fun isFriend(id:String,userListener:UserListener){
```

and

```
 fun isSendRequest(senderId:String,receiverId:String,requestListener: RequestListener){
```

the firebase Firestore is basically an async function. Once called it will only run and update contents inside it, i.e., inside `addOnCompleteListener`.

UserListener is not being updated because it might not be an async/callback function.

So, this is my suggestion and it might vary from person to person.

1. **Pass LiveData/MutableLiveData object** instead of UserListener. This is not the recommended way and even I wouldn't recommend it.
2. **Using RxJava**. This is another approach you can take.
   This is one of the articles I used to get started with Rxjava [Exploring RxJava in Android - Introduction](https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-rxjava-in-android-e52ed7ef32e2)
3. **Kotlin Flows - Specifically callbackFlow{}** Since android and kotlin are increasing their support for Kotlin Flows, I decided to shift to Kotlin Flows from RxJava.

I will explain how you can deal with your situation using callback flows.

First make a class, that holds the result and exceptions.

```
/**
 * A generic class that holds a value with its loading status.
 * @param <T>
 */
sealed class Result<out T : Any> {
    //change as per your need
    data class Success1<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Success2<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Success3<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

Now in the functions where you receive your data.

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun isSendRequest(senderId:String,receiverId:String):Flow<Result<SomeData>> = callbackFlow{

    db.collection("Users").document(receiverId).collection("Requests").document(senderId).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->

       if(task.exception!=null){trySend(Result.Error(task.exception))}
       if(task.isSuccessful && task.result.exists()){
         val yourData:SomeData = TODO("Logic Required")
         trySend(Result.Success2(yourData))
}
    }
}
```

> Note-- callbackFlow{} is annotated with @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi.
>
> Marks declarations that are still experimental in coroutines API, which means that the design of the corresponding declarations has open issues which may (or may not) lead to their changes in the future. Roughly speaking, there is a chance that those declarations will be deprecated in the near future or the semantics of their behavior may change in some way that may break some code.